# How to call receiver one a hour?

Tags: android, time, broadcastreceiver, call, hour

Is it possible to call receiver only on start of every new hour? I have running service and I need to call receiver only when the time changes from for example: five o'clock to six o'clock, etc.? Is there any way how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use an `AlarmManager`. Then schedule  the times you want it to notify you. Google for more examples.

UPDATE:

What you can do is wake it up at the next hour, at 8.00 if time is 7.30 . Then shedule it for an hourly wake up the next time it starts.

```
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR,c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+1);
            c.getTimeInMillis(); // use this in alarmmanager for the first time, 60*60*1000 from next time
```

Comment: I know how to use AlarmManager, but problem is that for example, when service starts at 7:30, and I set AlarmManager to wake after 60 minutes, so it will wake at 8:30, etc.

Comment: So it should look like this alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), c.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent); ?

Comment: m.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),60*60*1000, p);

Comment: I solved it yesterday with similar code, but mainly I had to change ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP to RTC_WAKEUP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of GregorianCalendar and an AlarmManager for this. You basically add 1 hour to the current time and then round downwards to the nearest hour. See an example here:

```
long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1 hour in milliseconds.

Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(); // Get current time
c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1); // Add one hour to the current time.

// Set minutes, second, millisecond to 0, such that we ensure that an update is done
// at the end of the hour.
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

// Set an alarm, starting from the end of the current hour, every hour, to execute
// the update service.
// pIntent is the pending intent you would like activate.
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, c.getTimeInMillis(), UPDATE_INTERVAL, pIntent);
```

I assume you know how to call the receiver.